# Prevent <span> tags ASP.NET server control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an issue with this span tags. they are generated but i dont want them. how can i remove them ?

I have the following code

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbl_items" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Flow"  Visible="true" ClientIDMode="Static"  >


</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Renders this

```
<span> 
<input> 
<label> 
<br> 
<input> 
<label>
<br> 
(...)
< /span>
```

And i wanted something like

```
   < label>< input (radio)>< /label>
   < label>< input (radio)>< /label>
```

In other words how can i remove the < span> tags and if possible structure the render html to be like the client wants(as i showed).

Thanks

Comment: I am new to c# and i would appreciate some help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach to get rid of span is to follow the technique mentioned [Here](http://aspnetresources.com/blog/stripping_span_from_webcontrol)

Another would be, to use the input control of html and place runat="server" and ID attribute and use in code behind.

Another would be to use something like this:

```
<ul ID="rbl_items" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" style="list-style: none;"></ul>

Code Behind:

int count = 0;
foreach (var yourObj in YourList)
        {
            HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
            HtmlInputRadioButton radioButton = new HtmlInputRadioButton
            {
                Value = yourObj,
                Name = "controlGroup",
                ID = "controlID" + count
            };
            li.Controls.Add(radioButton);
            Label label = new Label { Text = yourObj, CssClass = "YourCSSClass", AssociatedControlID = "controlID"+count };
            li.Controls.Add(label);
            rbl_items.Controls.Add(li);
            count++;
        }
```

You can set style for ul and li later.

Comment: protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
 RenderContents (writer);
} this is the answer in the topic u gaved, but where do i place this ? Sorry im Newbie in c# :/ u said to use input right? but i cant since radiobuttonlist item are  dynamic

Comment: He created a class for the object? i didnt im using a radiobuttonlist control from the aplication

Comment: Well, this method could be complex for you. So, see if you can use html controls with runat=server attribute..

Comment: To use html controls i had to have sure of how many items the radiobuttonlist would have right? but she is dynamically created that's why i "think" i cant use html controls.

Comment: Are you adding any event for radiobuttonlist or radio button in code behind? Or any Class or style?

Comment: No im binding radiobutton items in the page load with a list.

Comment: one more suggestion, use InputAttributes instead of Attributes in code behind.. Also, you can use HtmlInputRadioButton instead of using List Item in RadioButtonList and add the HtmlInputRadioButton object in the same RadioButtonList.. Hope it helps.. cheers :)

Comment: Thanks for the effort and the help ! it worked for me

Comment: Thats great. Glad it helped